# Disabling windows key in a c# windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I disable windows key in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361109/how-can-i-disable-windows-key-in-c)

How can I disable windows key in my c# windows app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361109/how-can-i-disable-windows-key-in-c

Exactly the same question with a couple good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library:

http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

As an example using this lib with following snippet you can disables WinKey + R combination.
There are two steps 1. Detect the combination 2. Disable further handling by setting `e.Handled = true`.
Hope it helps.

```
private KeyboardHookListener m_KeyboardHookManager;
private bool m_LeftWinKeyIsDown;
private bool m_RightWinKeyIsDown;

private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_KeyboardHookManager = new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker());
    m_KeyboardHookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
    m_KeyboardHookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
    m_KeyboardHookManager.Enabled = true;
}

private void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.LWin) m_LeftWinKeyIsDown = true;
    if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.RWin) m_RightWinKeyIsDown = true;
    if ((m_LeftWinKeyIsDown || m_RightWinKeyIsDown) && e.KeyCode == Keys.R) e.Handled = true;
}

private void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin) m_LeftWinKeyIsDown = false;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.RWin) m_RightWinKeyIsDown = false;
}
```

Comment: CodePlex Archive will be shut down after July 1st, 2021, so this library is now on GitHub:
[https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)