# how can I restrict opening start window when window key is pressed in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created the wpf application where i have given the windowskey + s as the shortcutkey.But while pressing window key the start window is opening.how can i restrict it.

```
 private void keyboardHook_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMousePoint)
            {
                if (e.Shift)
                {
                    w.Show();
                }
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == (System.Windows.Forms.Keys.LWin & System.Windows.Forms.Keys.S))
            {

                if (inRecord)
                    StopRecordAction(null);
                else
                    RecordProject(mainWindow);
            }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Pls, show us some of your code.

Comment: Looks like you handling `KeyDown` event?

Comment: Yes Im handling it in keyDown event.

Comment: Then you have to set low-level keyboard windows hook. Here is a [good sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante).

Comment: vasily can you please say how it helps to restrict the start window.Since I don't have idea if you share your knowledge It will be helpful to implement it

Comment: ok, if I have some time, I will post a sample (there is a lot of work)

Comment: oh, one more question. Are you sure, that this is WPF application? `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` and `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` is from WinForms:\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I disable windows key in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361109/how-can-i-disable-windows-key-in-c)

Comment: Vasily.sib this is the wpf application.